# Does Jaspersoft Studio correctly read Fields for conditional queries?

Tags: sql, parameters, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I've got conditional SQL queries which are getting selected by a controller if certain conditions are met. If I press "read Fields" I only get the fields for one of the queries.

The queries are correct and if pasted directly into the *queryString* I get the correct Fields for each of them.

Query 1:

```
<parameter name="SQLTag" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" evaluationTime="Late">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["SELECT * FROM REPORT_VER WHERE TAG BETWEEN '" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format($P{Von})  + "' AND '" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format($P{Bis}) + "'"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Query 2 (with constants in the dates because of testing purpose):

```
<parameter name="SQLMonat" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["select to_char(tag,'MON') as Monat, sum(Hauptnutzungszeit) as MonatsNutzung from report_ver where Tag between '10.05.2015' and '20.05.2015' group by  to_char(tag,'MON')"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

controller:

```
<parameter name="controller" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false" evaluationTime="Late">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["täglich".equals($P{Ansicht})? $P{SQLTag} : (("monatlich".equals($P{Ansicht}) ? $P{SQLMonat} : $P{SQLTag}))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

*queryString*:

```
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[ $P!{controller} ]]>
</queryString>
```

Everything worked fine for only one query, so I don't think there is a problem with the connector. Do i need to add the fields manually? or how do I get all of the fields?

If I run the report without all fields, I obviously get the error message that certain fields are missing.

Comment: Is this question about using *Jaspersoft Studio*? Or *iReport*?

Comment: Jaspersoft Studio

Comment: any ideas? I'm still facing this problem....

Comment: You can add fields manually (by editing *jrxml* file or via JSS dialog)

Comment: When you are working with dynamic SQL then your column should be present otherwise it wont run if field is not found ?

Comment: @Alex k if the fields selected is dynamic, then it is impossible to manually add it in jasper studio